# How to use TBufferedTransport of TThreadedSelectorServer in java

Tags: java, python, thrift

How to use TBufferedTransport of TThreadedSelectorServer in java?

in Python client:

```
self.tsocket= TSocket.TSocket(self.host, self.port)
self.transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(self.tsocket)
protocol = TBinaryProtocol(self.transport)
client = Handler.Client(protocol)
self.transport.open()
```

in Java Server

```
TNonblockingServerSocket serverTransport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(port);
TProcessor tprocessor = new ExecutionService.Processor<ExecutionService.Iface>(handler);
TThreadedSelectorServer.Args tArgs = new TThreadedSelectorServer.Args(serverTransport);
tArgs.processor(tprocessor);
tArgs.protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());
this.server = new TThreadedSelectorServer(tArgs);
```

The Python client uses TBufferedTransport, and the Java server uses TFramedTransport. Causes an exception:

```
AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer  Read an invalid frame size of -2147418111. Are you using TFramedTransport on the client side?
```

For some reasons, the client cannot be modified, so I want to modify the java server to TBufferedTransport.
How to use TBufferedTransport of TThreadedSelectorServer in java?
thanks！！！

Answer (score 0):

The `TThreadedSelectorServer` requires `TFramedTransport` ([reference](https://people.apache.org/%7Ethejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/server/TThreadedSelectorServer.html)):

> A Half-Sync/Half-Async server with a separate pool of threads to handle non-blocking I/O. Accepts are handled on a single thread, and a configurable number of nonblocking selector threads manage reading and writing of client connections. ... Like TNonblockingServer, it relies on the use of TFramedTransport.

This applies for the other non-blocking server classes deriving from `TNonblockingServer` ([reference](https://people.apache.org/%7Ethejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/server/TNonblockingServer.html)):

> A nonblocking TServer implementation. This allows for fairness amongst all connected clients in terms of invocations. This server is inherently single-threaded. If you want a limited thread pool coupled with invocation-fairness, see THsHaServer. To use this server, you MUST use a TFramedTransport at the outermost transport, otherwise this server will be unable to determine when a whole method call has been read off the wire. Clients must also use TFramedTransport.

If you cannot use `TFramedTransport` on the client side, you therefore have to use a blocking server, i.e. `TThreadPoolServer` ([reference](https://people.apache.org/%7Ethejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/server/TThreadPoolServer.html)):

> Server which uses Java's built in ThreadPool management to spawn off a worker pool that deals with client connections in blocking way.

Your code would then look like this:

```
      TServerSocket serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);
      TThreadPoolServer.Args tArgs = new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport);
      tArgs.processor(processor);
      tArgs.protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());
      TThreadPoolServer server = new TThreadPoolServer(tArgs);
```

To detail the differences between the blocking and the non-blocking servers (for general reference, apologies if the difference is already clear to you): Blocking means that when data is read from a socket, no other operation can be done while reading. So when the data arrives partially, the current thread waits until the remaining data arrives. So when a blocking server only has a single thread, only one client can be handled at a time. The time spend waiting for further data from a client cannot be used to serve other clients.

To support multiple clients, multiple threads can be added (as done for `TThreadPoolServer`). Each thread can only handle one client at a time as before, so the number of clients that can be served simultaneously is limited by the number of threads. You could of course spawn many threads, but this does not scale well: The threads used by the Java `ThreadPool` which backs the `TThreadPoolServer` are system-level threads, so they come with some resource over-head for creation and switching between threads. So creating a large number of threads to serve a large number of clients means more time is spent with OS book-keeping of the tasks.

Non-blocking servers (deriving from `TNonblockingServer`) are meant to solve this problem by utilizing the time spend waiting for data from one client by reading data from other clients. This way a single thread can handle multiple clients, reading from whichever client currently has available data. A non-blocking server can of course also have multiple threads, each handling multiple clients. This way the number of threads does not have to scale with the number of clients. Instead, the number of threads can be chosen proportionally to the number of CPU cores, and then each thread running on a core can read as much data as the I/O band-width and CPU speed allows. For this reason, a non-blocking server scales better with high-client numbers.

For this reason, if you have to handle a large number of clients simultaneously , using `TNonblockingServer` would be preferable and it would be better to find a way to switch the client to use the `TFramedTransport`. If your use-case is handling only a limited number of clients, then using `TThreadPoolServer` without modifying the client should be fine, even if each client produces a lot of data.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem perfectly